# Asterisk AGI and Mysql string variabile

Tags: mysql, asterisk, agi

I can not solve a problem, The purpose of the script is to identify the context number.

Below is the asterisk dial plan extensions.conf

```
exten => 1234,1,Answer()
same => n,Set(NUM2CALL=Hello, your number is eight)
same => n,NOOP(${NUM2CALL})
same => n,AGI(test.php,${NUM2CALL})
```

The file that is running test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/phpagi/phpagi.php';
$agi = new AGI();

//DB connect
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'testdatabase', 'asterisk');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());

    exit();
}
//End

$query  = "SELECT text, number FROM recognation_2";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    if(strpos($argv[1], $row->text) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo $row->number;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: <SIP/100-000030c4>AGI Tx >> 510 Invalid or unknown command
[Oct 31 11:35:49] ERROR[20679]: utils.c:1164 ast_carefulwrite: write() returned error: Broken pipe
    -- <SIP/100-000030c4>AGI Script test.php completed, returning 0

Comment: you dont need agi class for this. remove them and try to debug on console like "php myfile.php" it gives some hints to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you kidding? Why just not ask db one line?

```
$query  = "SELECT text, number FROM recognation_2 where text = "+mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$argv[1]);
```

Best option for this task is just use func_odbc, no need any php or agi.